# Combine two rows into new column mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running an SQL query that provides the result set as shown below. I am merging results coming from `jobentry` (which is for employees working during normal hours) and `overtimejobentry` (which is for employees working overtime).

What I would like to do is combine rows that have the same `jobNumber` and `wbsCode` so that the normal hours and overtime hours appear within the same row for each job and code.

Is there a way I can combine two rows into one and create a new column for the additional data?

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT 
    fk_jobNumber AS jobNumber,
    wbsCode,
    SUM(tue + wed + thu + fri + mon) AS totalHours
FROM
    jobentry
        INNER JOIN
    task ON task.taskID = jobentry.fk_taskID
        INNER JOIN
    wbscodeitem ON wbscodeitem.wbsCodeItemID = task.fk_wbsCodeItemID
        INNER JOIN
    job ON job.jobNumber = wbscodeitem.fk_jobNumber
GROUP BY fk_jobNumber , wbsCode 

UNION

/*Same SQL statement as above except it's for table overtimejobentry instead of jobentry*/
SELECT 
    fk_jobNumber AS jobNumber,
    wbsCode,
    SUM(tue + wed + thu + fri + sat + sun + mon) AS totalHours
FROM
    overtimejobentry
        INNER JOIN
    task ON task.taskID = overtimejobentry.fk_taskID
        INNER JOIN
    wbscodeitem ON wbscodeitem.wbsCodeItemID = task.fk_wbsCodeItemID
        INNER JOIN
    job ON job.jobNumber = wbscodeitem.fk_jobNumber
GROUP BY fk_jobNumber , wbsCode
```

**Result:**

```
jobNumber   wbsCode   totalHours
--------------------------------
10             88            25   (from jobentry table)
10            552            70   (from jobentry table)
25             17           150   (from jobentry table)
25            374            38   (from jobentry table)
10             88            63   (from overtimejobentry table)
25            374            12   (from overtimejobentry table)
```

**This is what I am trying to do:**

```
jobNumber   wbsCode   totalHours   totalOvertimeHours
----------------------------------------------------- 
10             88            25                    63
10            552            70                     0
25             17           150                     0
25            374            38                    12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pivot to bring the two types of hours into a single record for each job number and WBS code.  In the query below, I have added a computed column called `type` which keeps track of the origin of the hours either from regular hours or from overtime.

```
SELECT t.jobNumber,
       t.wbsCode,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.type = 'normal'   THEN totalHours END) AS totalHours,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.type = 'overtime' THEN totalHours END) AS totalOvertimeHours
FROM
(
    SELECT fk_jobNumber AS jobNumber,
           wbsCode,
           SUM(tue + wed + thu + fri + mon) AS totalHours,
           'normal' AS type      -- remember which records come from normal hours
    FROM jobentry
    INNER JOIN task
        ON task.taskID = jobentry.fk_taskID
    INNER JOIN wbscodeitem
        ON wbscodeitem.wbsCodeItemID = task.fk_wbsCodeItemID
    INNER JOIN job
        ON job.jobNumber = wbscodeitem.fk_jobNumber
    GROUP BY fk_jobNumber, wbsCode 

    UNION        -- note: you might want to use UNION ALL here

    SELECT fk_jobNumber AS jobNumber,
           wbsCode,
           SUM(tue + wed + thu + fri + sat + sun + mon) AS totalHours,
           'overtime' AS type    -- remember which records come from overtime hours
    FROM overtimejobentry
    INNER JOIN task
        ON task.taskID = overtimejobentry.fk_taskID
    INNER JOIN wbscodeitem
        ON wbscodeitem.wbsCodeItemID = task.fk_wbsCodeItemID
    INNER JOIN job
        ON job.jobNumber = wbscodeitem.fk_jobNumber
    GROUP BY fk_jobNumber, wbsCode
) t
GROUP BY t.jobNumber,
         t.wbsCode
```

Note that a possible alternative to wrapping with a subquery, as done above, would be to join your two subqueries together.  The problem here is that a given job number and WBS code combination might appear in one, but not the other.  In that case, we might have to resort to a full outer join, for which MySQL does not have built in support.  The answer given above would most likely be much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the response, its working as intended although changing `GROUP BY t.fk_jobNumber` towards the end of the query to `GROUP BY t.jobNumber` is required.